# gcloud-aio-storage can't upload more than 2GB data

Tags: python, upload, gcloud

[gcloud-aio-storage](https://talkiq.github.io/gcloud-aio/autoapi/storage/index.html#usage) is working in-memory fashion. It requires file content to upload, while we try to get file content from a larger file (more than 2GB), it says:

> OverflowError: string longer than 2147483647 bytes

Can anyone knows what to do to accept a larger file?

My implemented code is:

```
import aiofiles
import asyncio
from gcloud.aio.storage import Storage

async def upload(bucket, file, contents):
    async with Storage() as client:
        await client.upload(bucket, file, contents)

async def uploads(bucket, obj_names):
    for file in obj_names:
        async with aiofiles.open(file, mode="r") as f:
            contents = await f.read() # This line causes the issue
            await upload(bucket, file, contents)
```

Environment:

OS: Windows 11 (64 bit)

Python: Python 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: Do you recognize what `2147483647` is and means? And no it is not 2 GB. What are you running your code on? I am guessing you are running a 32-bit version of Python.

Comment: Note: if you are using strings that large, you will need an instance size with enough memory to hold the string. Upload objects in chunks.

Comment: @JohnHanley My python version: `Python 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Comment: 64-bit Python supports 2⁶³ - 1 bytes. That means you are leaving important details out of your question. Let me ask again - what are you running your code on?

Comment: Do you mean which OS? I am running it on windows-11 locally not any docker environment.

Comment: @JohnHanley What do you mean by "what are you running your code on?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256171/discussion-between-arif-and-john-hanley).